# Sail back-end app not working when running a front-end app with vite at the same time

Tags: laravel, vite, laravel-sail

I have an application made of two separate projects: a back-end built with Laravel and a front-end built with Vue and Vite. I used to run the back with Homestead (on a custom test host) and the front with vite (on http://localhost:8080).

I tried to migrate on Laravel Sail to run the back-end. The back app works if I don't start the vite server. As soon as I start the vite server, the back stops responding (requests timeout).
Even after stopping the vite server, I have to restart sail to make the back responding again.

Here is my docker-composer.yml, for the back app:

```
version: '3'
services:
    custom.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
            IGNITION_LOCAL_SITES_PATH: '${PWD}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

Here's my vite.config.js, for the front app:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2';

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
    strictPort: true
  },
  plugins: [
    vue()
  ]
});
```

I'm running Docker on a Mac.

Docker ps prints :

```
% docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS                 PORTS                                                  NAMES
c8e72d93f60a   sail-8.2/app             "start-container"        6 hours ago   Up 6 hours             0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5173->5173/tcp, 8000/tcp   back-custom.test-1
05fccfa8fe25   mysql/mysql-server:8.0   "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   6 hours ago   Up 6 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060-33061/tcp                back-mysql-1
```

Thank for the help.

Comment: are you starting frontend with `npm` or `yarn`? or it has its own docker image?

Comment: Also, can you run `docker ps` before and after running the frontend and add its output to your question?

Comment: I am running frontend with npm on my mac os.

Comment: I have added the output of docker ps in my question.

Comment: What happens after you stop the vite server? Can you reach your backend after stopping vite? Have you tried swapping the run order? First, run your vite server then `docker compose up`.

Comment: Same behavior if I swap the run order. If I stop the vite server, the back still not responds. I have to restart it to make it work again.

Comment: I finally found the reason of the issue. I was using Laravel Passport (Oauth) and calls to the OAuth server were not working or blocked. I removed Passport for another auth solution and now it works.